# best database to use for my ionic project

Tags: database, local-storage, ionic-framework

I’m looking for the best database to use for my ionic project. I want the user to store the database locally with the option of synchronizing that information a remote database as a payment option. Their data will be from any device by login to their user account. I have been looking at firebase Couchdb, and Parse but don’t know what I should go with.  I have to keep in mind scaling my app. What are the best options out there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LocalStorage is a great option if there is not much data to store locally. Or if you need a more flexible and larger database you might want to try IndexedDB or SQLite Plugin for Cordova(Ionic is built on top of Cordova), all of these options are for the client end.

But for the server end, I have used FireBase for one of my projects and I know it works like charm, if you are familiar with [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/)/Web Components all you have to do to have [FireBase](https://github.com/polymer/firebase-element), add just one line of html and everything else is set up for you.

**Links:**
[Cordova-LocalStorage Docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage)
[SQLite-plugin Docs](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin)

Comment: I have been developing with the SQLite plugin up to this point in my project.  Can you limit the database size with SQLite plugin?  Would I be able to sync the SQLite database with firebase database of would localstorage be better for this?

Comment: You can use Lokijs also http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-use-lokijs-for-local-storage-in-your-ionic-app/

Answer (score 4):

You could use [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com) a noSQL javascript couchDB clone. It can synchronizes with a remote couchDB database and is easy to use in a local enviroment.

Comment: I think this is what I am going to do.  Do these technologies scale well?